# MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Why am I getting the following Build error?

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe C:\Code\EduBenesysNET\EduBenesysNET\EduBenesysNET.vbproj /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /v:detailed /p:PublishDir="\\BSIIS3\c$\DATA\WEBSITES\benesys.net\benesys.net\TotalEducationTest\"  /p:InstallUrl="https://www.benesys.net/benesys.net/TotalEducationTest/"  /p:ApplicationVersion=1.0.1.198  /p:ProductName="Total Education TEST"   /p:PublisherName="BeneSys, Inc."  /p:UpdateRequired="True"  /p:MinimumRequiredVersion=1.0.1.198
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3603]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: Education

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

I do not see how a second project is being specified.
Is it stored in a project file somewhere?

Comment: The very same command works in powershell but not in cmd.exe... looks like you are hitting a spacial character sequance somewhere...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
Remove the Quotes around the /p:PublishDir setting

i.e.
Instead of quotes

```
/p:PublishDir="\\BSIIS3\c$\DATA\WEBSITES\benesys.net\benesys.net\TotalEducationTest\"
```

Use no quotes

```
/p:PublishDir=\\BSIIS3\c$\DATA\WEBSITES\benesys.net\benesys.net\TotalEducationTest\
```

I am sorry I did not post my finding sooner. I actually had to research again to see what needed to be changed. Who would have thought removing quotes would have worked? I discovered this when viewing a coworkers build for another solution and noticed it did not have quotes.

Comment: This is very strange.  In my case I got the same error but the problem is that I had an unquoted path with a space in it.  Adding the quotes fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue as @MarkArnott, it did not work with spaces or escaped spaces, but quoting did.

Comment: Probably the last backslash in your path was escaping the closing double-quote.  If correct, then you didn't need to remove the double-quotes, but instead you needed to escape your backslashes.

Comment: Remember, the spaces in dir path needs to be escaped or have to be placed inside a double quotes

Comment: With double quotes: PublishDir="C:\xxx\yyy"  (also publishUrl=)  worked for me

Answer (score 156):

It turns out the trailing slash in the PublishDir property is escaping the end quote. Escaping the trailing slash solved my problem.

```
/p:PublishDir="\\BSIIS3\c$\DATA\WEBSITES\benesys.net\benesys.net\TotalEducationTest\\"
```

This way we can use quotes for paths that have whitespace in properties that MSBuild requires the trailing slash.

I know this is an old post, but I feel like I needed to share this with someone :-)

Answer (score 63):

On Git Bash I had to specify the parameters with double slashes like:

```
MSBuild.exe "Path\to\Solution.sln" //p:Platform="x86" //p:Configuration=Release //p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86"
```

Comment: Look like this is the root cause, related on how Git_Bash works on POSIX path starting with a slash putting in the mix the windows style paths

Double slashes solve or you can disable automatic path conversion to keep interoperability

history: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion

Release notes
https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/a9090580ee37686a53166796dffda531041e16f8/ReleaseNotes.md

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `-p` instead of `/p`.

Comment: `-p` works for me also

Answer (score 34):

This problem appears when you have a path or a property containing a space and that is not quoted.

All your properties and path have quote around them, it's strange. The error message indicates `Education` as a switch, try to remove `/p:ProductName="Total Education TEST"` to see if it works.

Comment: Avoid Space in folder path to get rid of this issue.

Comment: @Julien Hoarau: I tried `MSBuild.exe C:\BuildAgent\work\4c7b8ac8bc7d723e\WebService.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=bin /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://204.158.674.5/msdeploy.axd /p:username=Admin /p:password=Password#321 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployIisAppPath=Default WebSite/New /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC`. It gives me an error  `MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. Switch: WebSite/New`. What might be the issue?

Comment: @NevinRajVictor A lot late, but probably you should put quotes around `Default WebSite/New`

Answer (score 12):

You need to put qoutes around the path and file name.
So use 
MSBuild "C:\Path Name\File Name.Exe" /[Options]

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the trailing backslash or slash at the end of you publish path and install url

```
/p:PublishDir="\\BSIIS3\c$\DATA\WEBSITES\benesys.net\benesys.net\TotalEducationTest"
/p:InstallUrl="https://www.benesys.net/benesys.net/TotalEducationTest"
```

You must have hit a special sequence of characters with the \" and (or) /", but I don't know enough in cmd.exe to figure out.

I personnaly always use Powershell : it's way more friendly and powerful!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I was using single quotes around the password parameter when I got the error

`/p:password='my secret'` bad

and changed it to use double quotes to resolve the issue.

`/p:password="my secret"` good

Likely the same would apply to any parameter that needs quotes for values that contain a space.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another cause and solution to this: Check that you didn't put a space in the wrong place, i.e. in parameters; mine was `dotnet -c Release - o /home/some/path` (note the space between `-` and `o`), I kept looking at the path itself, which was correct and threw me off. Hope that helps! (this was in Bash though it should also apply to Windows)

Answer (score 3):

In vs2012 just try to create a Build definition "Test Build" using the default TFS template  "DefaultTemplate....xaml" (usually a copy of it)

It will fail with the usual self-explaining-error: "MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.Switch: Activities"

Off course somewhere in the default TFS template some `"` are missing so msbuild will receive as parameter a non escaped directory containing spaces so will result in multiple projects(?!)

So NEVER use spaces in you TFS  Build Definition names, pretty sad and simple at the same time

Comment: This answer could use some tidying up. Very difficult to follow.

Comment: The point about Never using spaced in your TFS Build Definition names is a good one!  This has caught me multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

For me I had forgot to add closing quote

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true;OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

to

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true;OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"`

Comment: I was also missing closing double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Azure DevOps `MSBuild` task the error may be caused by doubled configuration flag. Please make sure you put `$(BuildConfiguration)` in specified box instead of MSBuild Arguments one:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me adding the path to the solution file in double quotes solved the issue. One of the folders in the path had a blank space in the name and this caused it to consider 2 solution files instead of one.
I executed in the following was and it worked.

`MSBuild.exe "C:\Folder Name With Space\Project\project.sln"`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was the switches. I resolved it by using -p instead of /p.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in TFS MSBuild Argument.  Note the number of slashes.

/p:DefaultPackageOutputDir="\\Rdevnet\Visual Studio Projects\Insurance\"

Answer (score 1):

If you use default workspace in Jenkins, this might occur.
Use custom workspace location without any spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For future readers.

I got this error because my specified LOG file had a space in it:

BEFORE:

```
/l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=c:\Folder With Spaces\My_Log.log
```

AFTER: (which resolved it)

```
/l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile="c:\Folder With Spaces\My_Log.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Any CPU` you may need to put it in single quotes.

Certainly when running in a Dockerfile, I had to use single quotes:

```
# Fails. Gives: MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
RUN msbuild ConsoleAppFw451.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" 

# Passes. Gives: Successfully built 40163c3e0121
RUN msbuild ConsoleAppFw451.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform='Any CPU'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
dotnet build -c Release --no-restore -p:Version=${VERSION} -p:Description=${DESCRIPTION}
```

I had this error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
```

But I changed it:

```
-p:Description=${DESCRIPTION}
```

to

```
-p:Description="${DESCRIPTION}"
```

And works.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same issue as me, I was missing "/" before one of the "/p" arguments. Not very clear from the description. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I did use solution given in https://www.codingdefined.com/2014/10/solved-msbuild-error-msb1008-only-one.html and that solves the issue. All we need to do is check spaces and ''(check backslashes) in the command

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with a very simple command, which didn't include any quote, any space, any slash, anything strange at all.

I was using MINGW64 shell.

The same exact command from PowerShell worked instead.

Answer (score 0):

With **.NET 6 CLI**, I face the "**MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.**" when running the test command with -d

**Not Work**

```
 dotnet test Abc.Tests.csproj -d "verbose_log.txt"
```

**Work**

```
 dotnet test Abc.Tests.csproj -d="verbose_log.txt"
 dotnet test Abc.Tests.csproj -d:"verbose_log.txt"
 dotnet test Abc.Tests.csproj --diag "verbose_log.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread with a lot of answers ... anyway, my solution was to write out `/property` (instead of only using `/p`).

E.g.:

```bash
dotnet publish path/to/project/ -c Release /property:AssemblyVersion=1.2.3.4 /property:Version=1.2.3.4-alpha -o path/to/out/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I'd combined multiple commands eg: "clean publish". Can't blame me for trying porting Gradle and Maven CLI practices to Dotnet CLI.